# get data by left join with count() for each row

Tags: php, sql

My code:

```
$q = mysql_query("
            SELECT 
                ads.title_ad AS title_ad, 
                COUNT(adclicks.ad_id) AS counted, 
                ads.dclicks AS dclicks
            FROM ads
            LEFT JOIN adclicks 
                ON ads.id = adclicks.ad_id GROUP BY ads.id
    ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
    if($row['counted'] > $row['dclicks'])
    {
    }
    else
    {
        echo ''.$row['title_ad'].' '.$row['counted'].' '.$row['dclicks'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

I just want to remove `if(){}` and want to adjust it in sql query.

Whats the  solution? How to do that?

Comment: what you mean ? remove if() {} ???

Comment: TO REMOVE THIS :if($row['counted'] > $row['dclicks'])
    {
    }
    else
    {
        echo ''.$row['title_ad'].' '.$row['counted'].' '.$row['dclicks'].'<br>';
    }

Answer (score 0):

Add a HAVING clause to your SQL:

```
HAVING COUNT(adclicks.ad_id) < ads.dclicks
```

Comment: can you provide any other details?  The HAVING clause filters out the results that are being skipped in the code's if statement.  You could also use: HAVING COUNT(adclicks.ad_id) >= ads.dclicks.

Comment: You could also move the concatenated result into your SQL like this:

SELECT title_ad + ' ' + CAST(counted AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(dclicks AS VARCHAR) + '<br/>'
FROM 
(
SELECT ads.title_ad AS title_ad, 
       COUNT(adclicks.ad_id) AS counted, 
       ads.dclicks AS dclicks
FROM ads
LEFT JOIN adclicks ON ads.id = adclicks.ad_id GROUP BY ads.id
)T1